# How to speed up ST_Union PostGIS query for complex problem

Tags: postgis, vector, merge, insert, st-union

I'm fairly new to working with PostGIS and have experienced the issue of extremely long runtimes when working on my data.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have an infrastructure dataset that is made up of tiles of 1x1 km. All the different types of infrastructure (roads, bikeways etc.) are stored are Polygons with a numeric class value indicating the type of infrastructure. Now if for example a road runs through multiple tiles I want to merge the road polygons that are touching each other to get one road polygon instead of multiple polygons that are separated by the tile borders.

I came up with the following PostGIS code that does what I need. However the runtime is really long (about 2 min for 6 tiles) and seems to rise inlineary when adding more tiles (almost 6 mins with 12 tiles). The table I'm working with is urmo_test4.
As wished, I try to walk you through my Query: First I'm grouping the polygons using their class and geometry giving each cluster a cluster id. After that the clustered polygons are merged using ST_Union with ST_Dump to get single polygons instead of multipolygons. This procedure results in many different variants of merged polygons instead of only one largest polygon, so I extract only the largest merged polygon from the merging and insert it into the table permanent_largest_merged_polygons. From this table I insert the largest merged polygons back into my original table urmo_test4. Here I now delete old polygons that are now within the polygons that I have inserted into the table to avoid overlapping polygons. The result are the merged polygons that span across the tile borders.

```
    CREATE TABLE permanent_largest_merged_polygons (
    class NUMERIC,
    merged_geometry geometry(Polygon));

WITH GroupedPolygons AS (
    SELECT
        a.class, 
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(a.geometry, eps :=0, minpoints := 2) OVER () AS cluster_id,
        a.geometry
    FROM urmo_test4 a
),
UnionedPolygons AS (
    SELECT 
        class, 
        cluster_id,
        (ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(geometry)))).geom AS merged_geometry
    FROM GroupedPolygons
    GROUP BY class, cluster_id
),
LargestMergedPolygons AS (
    SELECT 
        class, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY ST_Area(merged_geometry) DESC) AS rn,
        merged_geometry
    FROM UnionedPolygons
)

INSERT INTO permanent_largest_merged_polygons (class, merged_geometry) SELECT class, merged_geometry FROM LargestMergedPolygons;

CREATE INDEX permanent_largest_merged_polygons_geom_idx
    ON permanent_largest_merged_polygons
    USING GIST (merged_geometry);

INSERT INTO urmo_test4 (class, geometry)
SELECT 
    class,
    merged_geometry
FROM permanent_largest_merged_polygons;

DELETE FROM urmo_test4
USING permanent_largest_merged_polygons
WHERE st_within(urmo_test4.geometry, permanent_largest_merged_polygons.merged_geometry) AND urmo_test4.class = permanent_largest_merged_polygons.class AND ST_Area(urmo_test4.geometry) < ST_Area(permanent_largest_merged_polygons.merged_geometry);
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to speed this up? To me my solution also seems like a very complex solution to a somewhat uncomplex issue. So I'm open to any suggestions whether for speeding up or making the code less complex.

Answer (score 1):

The `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` function can be very slow, and may not actually be needed.

A first suggestion that springs to mind is however dependent on the CRS of the geometries and the make-up of the tiles. If coordinates are stored in meter-units, and the boundaries of the 1x1 km tiles are "round" kilometers (facilitating an efficient way to check whether a geometry touches a boundary), than an option would be to first insert all geometries that *do not touch* a tile boundary, and then insert those geometries that *do touch* tile boundaries (the only ones that actually need `ST_Union` and `ST_Dump`).

Something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO permanent_largest_merged_polygons 
-- First those geometries that do not touch a km-tile boundary
SELECT "class", geometry
FROM urmo_test4
WHERE ST_Xmin(geometry) > floor(ST_XMin(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
  AND ST_Xmax(geometry) < ceiling(ST_XMax(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
  AND ST_Ymin(geometry) > floor(ST_YMin(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
  AND ST_Ymax(geometry) < ceiling(ST_YMax(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
-- Now add the second part
UNION ALL
-- All geometries that touch boundaries
SELECT "class", (ST_Dump(geometry)).geom AS geometry
FROM (
  SELECT "class", ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry
  FROM urmo_test4
  WHERE ST_Xmin(geometry) = floor(ST_XMin(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
     OR ST_Xmax(geometry) = ceiling(ST_XMax(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
     OR ST_Ymin(geometry) = floor(ST_YMin(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
     OR ST_Ymax(geometry) = ceiling(ST_YMax(geometry) / 1000) * 1000
  GROUP BY "class"
) AS GroupedPolygons
```